# Neuralnet package in R big error

Tags: r, neural-network, normalization

I am trying to figure out how to make the neuralnet package to work. I did some tests with data I created and with their outcomes (about 50 rows of data and three columns with the fourth being the outcome I wanted and it was made from simple mathematical executions like summing the other three columns) and so far so good. Then I decided to apply the package on real data. I downloaded the mpg dataset from here http://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/datasets.html

I was running the code bellow:

```
net<- neuralnet(cty~displ+year+cyl+hwy,
                datain, hidden=3)
```

Even if I have 3 hidden layers, or 8 or 18 the error is the same and the time that the package processes the data is relatively small from this amount of data (234 lines):

```
        Error Reached Threshold Steps
1 2110.173077    0.006277805853    54
```

Any good advice for this?

Comment: What is the error exactly, I have user neuralnet before with no major problems

Comment: No code error, but it gives a huge error as an output. How can I minimize this? It also gets no time to analyze the data which makes me thing that I am not applying this correct...

Comment: If you figured it out write a comment if you like!

Comment: Try to `scale` your input variables first.

Comment: I understand that big error may appear due to the fact that data do not correlate well. I scaled the data, assuming that you mean scale() function so I get sd=1. But, the data do not make any sense now if there is not a way to reverse the scaling and bring them back to the normal appearance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a scale problem i guess, you can normalize or scale it. 
There are differences between `scaling` and `normalizing`, it will affect your results and worths a separate question on SO:

### normalize inputs

```
norm.fun = function(x){ 
  (x - min(x))/(max(x) - min(x)) 
}

require(ggplot2) # load mpg dataset
require(neuralnet)

data = mpg[, c('cty', 'displ', 'year', 'cyl', 'hwy')]
data.norm = apply(data, 2, norm.fun)

net = neuralnet(cty ~ displ + year + cyl + hwy, data.norm, hidden = 2)
```

Then you can denormalize the data

```
# restore data 
y.net = min(data[, 'cty']) + net$net.result[[1]] * range(data[, 'cty'])
plot(data[, 'cty'], col = 'red')
points(y.net)
```

[image]

### scale inputs

```
data.scaled = scale(data)
net = neuralnet(cty ~ displ + year + cyl + hwy, data.scaled, hidden = 2)

# restore data 
y.sd = sd(data[, 'cty'])
y.mean = mean(data[, 'cty'])

y.net = net$net.result[[1]] * y.sd + y.mean
plot(data[, 'cty'], col = 'red')
points(y.net)
```

[image]

You can also try the *nnet* package, it's very fast:

```
require(nnet)

data2 = mpg
data2$year = scale(data2$year)
fit = nnet(cty ~ displ + year + cyl + hwy, size = 10, data = data2, linout = TRUE)
plot(mpg$cty)
points(fit$fitted.values, col = 'red')
```

Comment: How can I reverse the scaling process so I can now test the network with data that have no cty miles per galon?

BTW your answer is superb!!!

Comment: Thats the one I'm referring to!
My question now is that. Let's say for example that we have data that are : 2.4 (liters) 2003(model) 6(cyl) 25(hwy) how can we find back the cty? Because the data we have now is scaled.

PS: It's amazing how much information someone can learn from stackoverflow.

Comment: You're welcome. One last thing: instead of points, try a line plot - the differences will be very clear.

Comment: Hello there again! I ran the code and as I can see the error with scaled data is a bit bigger than the normalized. But when I transform the data back denirmalization gives big differences and descaling is more accurate. 
What is the best method?Normalizing or scaling?Because as I have red there is a difference to what the methods represent in statistics.

Comment: I edited the code of de-normalization so it gives now better outputs y.net =data.frame(min(data[, 'cty']) + data.norm[,'cty'] * (max(data[, 'cty'])-min(data[, 'cty'])))

Comment: Standartization is the way to go. See this: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10289/whats-the-difference-between-normalization-and-standardization

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enabling linear output in your neural net model through linear.output=TRUE label?

```
neuralnet(formula, data, hidden = 1, threshold = 0.01,
  stepmax = 1e+05, rep = 1, startweights = NULL,
  learningrate.limit = NULL, learningrate.factor = list(minus = 0.5,
  plus = 1.2), learningrate = NULL, lifesign = "none",
  lifesign.step = 1000, algorithm = "rprop+", err.fct = "sse",
  act.fct = "logistic", ****linear.output = TRUE****, exclude = NULL,
  constant.weights = NULL, likelihood = FALSE)
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for answering! Although, I haven't worked with R again for almost a decade and to be honest, I don't even remember the basic syntax.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32458422)