# High error in neuralnet

Tags: r, neural-network

I am trying to train a neural network using neuralnet in R, but am getting very high error terms (in the region of 1850).  The input variables are responses to a set of 6 likert scales (all on a 1-7) and the output is whether there was a topbox response to another variable (coded 0,1).  The input variables have been scaled to a 0,1 range (I've also tried normalizing to a mean of 0). I've tried a range of hidden nodes (from 1-10) and the network is converging to a threshold of 0.1 fairly reliably in 200000-400000 iterations, but with a consistent error term around 1800-1900. There are 30,000 cases in total, about 22000 in the training set. I appreciate that this type of problem doesn't need a neural network necessarily - this is proof of concept (going excellently...) on a familiar dataset before application to other questions. Any suggestions on how to reduce the error/improve the training net appreciated.

As I said, I have tried both normalising and scaling, and now also using the pca preprocessing provided in caret. Must be something in the data, but at a bit of a loss...

Code:

```
maxs <-apply(final, 2, max)
mins <-apply(final, 2, min)

scaled <-as.data.frame(scale(final, center=mins, scale=maxs-mins))
index<-sample(1:nrow(scaled), round(0.75*nrow(scaled)))    

train_ <-scaled[index,]
test_ <-scaled[-index,]


nn<-neuralnet(Q11~A1+B1+C1+D1+E1+Q12, data=train_, hidden=5, rep=1,threshold=0.01, stepmax=6e+05, linear.output=F, lifesign='full')
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'error terms' can you show specifically why you are referring to?  If not in the `nn` object how you are calculating them?

Comment: It's the error term produced by neuralnet, e.g
                                                 23000 min thresh: 0.5483619355
                                                 23223 error: 1847.13806 time: 1.97 mins

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add, I think this should represent the sum of the squared error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Neuralnet package in R big error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20665830/neuralnet-package-in-r-big-error)

Comment: Thanks - I have read that, but the main suggestion that this is due to normalization doesn't appear to be the case in this instance - I have tried both rescaling and normalising, to no avail